# Entity Framework "connection requested timed out " sporadic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework Code First to connect to an Oracle database. Several (random) times per day I get a "connection request timed out" error, with more detailed message, "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string".

Most of the time I can connect to the database no problem. Often if I stop and start my project in Visual Studio, the error will disappear next time I start the project.

I have checked with our DBA's and network team, and there are no apparent issues with the network or database availability.

My searches on the Internet have suggested that the above error message is concerned with my connection string, however, as I have said, the connection works smoothly most of the time.

Is there anything I can do to diagnose from my project what may be causing this intermittent problem?

Thanks!
Martin

Comment: Make sure you're creating a new connection each time instead of having one connection open the entire time for the app (global variable).

Comment: The error occurs when the project is restarted in Visual Studio..but only on random occasions. So, the connection will have been dropped and reopened just before the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that I have seen this as well. I'm also on the hunt for the definitive answer.

The outermost exception is 'System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

with Inner Exception message
"The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string."

with Inner Exception message
"Connection request timed out"

by Declaring Type: Name = PoolManager 3 FullName = OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager 3

The best I've noticed with this intermittent error behavior is that I've only gotten these errors when the DBContext is going through OnModelCreating. Perhaps the "Connection request timed out" is legitimately taking longer than the 15s default Connection Timeout?

If the problem comes back I may try to add additional ConnectionString variables such as Validate Connection=True; or to shut off Pooling or limit Connection Lifetime as a test.

Sorry I don't have the full answer yet.

Comment: Thanks Jason, that is spot on the same exception